# How to display the component with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to implement HMR for react/webpack/gulp, this is my component:

```
import React from 'react';

class main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>Hi this is fdsfdsfs</div>
        );
    }
}

export default main;
```

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './main';


ReactDOM.render(
    <main/>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I change a file I get:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
client:37 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
2client:37 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client:37 [WDS] App hot update...
only-dev-server.js:69 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
log-apply-result.js:20 [HMR] Updated modules:
log-apply-result.js:22 [HMR]  - 245
only-dev-server.js:55 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

The questions is why I cant see anything rendered on the page?
See also [here](https://github.com/dimitri-a/koekje)

Comment: It should be `<App />` not `<main />` - Also, name your components with uppercase as per convention, and lowercase tags will be treated as *regular HTML tags*.

Comment: lol that was quick, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Component names must always begin with Capital letters otherwise they are treated a regular HTML tags. Also You are importing your main component as App and using it as main again, which is incorrect.

```
import React from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>Hi this is fdsfdsfs</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './main';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Main/>
 ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```